# use DBNull.Value in SYBASE Database with MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, odbc

I'm working in a MVC ASP.NET project and have to insert data from a view into a SYBASE Database and before to insert via ODBCParameter I would like to check if the varchar value to insert has a real value(not null) in order to avoid an exception, for that I have created this ODBCParameter

```
OdbcParameter responsable = new OdbcParameter("@responsable", OdbcType.VarChar);
            if (data.Responsable.ToString()=="")
            {
                responsable.Value = DBNull.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                responsable.Value = data.Responsable.ToString();
            }
```

I would like to have your thoughts about this because it doesn't check if the value is null and doesn't save the responsable value into the database, actually I got the "not enough host for variables" what is wrong with the code? the insert statement only inserts the responsable value(just for debug purposes) and the data.Responsable is a string property.    the responsable field can hold null values in the database.

and one more question, is there any difference to use

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.Responsable.ToString()))
```

and

```
if (data.Responsable.ToString()=="")
```

Comment: is data.Responsable a string?

Comment: yes, it is a string property

Comment: Then you don't need to call ToString() on a string, if Responsable were null Responsable.ToString() will error.  If Responsable is null (Responsable == "") will be *false*, IsNullOrEmpty() ensures you get *true* for both - null & "".

Comment: If `data.Responsable` is a string property, then you should be using `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.Responsable))`. That's what it's made for. There's no need to use `.ToString()` on a string property.